# Do I need to create a tasks.json file in vscode everytime I want to build a new c/c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I don't want to create a new tasks.json file everytime I create a new project or code in c/c++. I want vscode to automatically detect it's extension and use the compiler accordingly(gcc for .c files and g++ for.cpp files).

Comment: I think this is a much harder problem than you think it is. You're much farther away from a one-size-fits all compilation command with C/C++ than you would be with some other languages. Especially because there isn't a dominant toolchain; it's far from the case that everyone is using GCC to compile.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer No, what I am saying is that when we use sublime text, it automatically builds our file based on it's extension i.e gcc for .c files and g++ for .cpp files. Can't we do something like that in vscode so that it automatically builds our file in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found an extension named Code-runner which automatically runs without us creating tasks.json file everytime.